# FFT Accelerometer

Tags: matlab, fft, accelerometer

I've some doubts against FFT plot of my accelerometer datas.

I use the MMA8451 accelerometer that has a 800Hz ODR but if I plot
FFT with Matlab (I use this tutorial [FFT Matlab](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)) I obtain a spike on a frequency that is double than as I expected.

In the Matlab script, what is the correct sample rate to set (Fs parameter)?

It's equal to ODR (800Hz) o correspond to the bandwidth of my signal that is for Nyquist ODR/2 (400Hz)?

Comment: Independently on `Fs`, if you are plotting as the demo shows, the frequency plot is in Hz, so you should be getting the frequency where it appears in the data. Nyquist says that you need to sample AT LEAST at double the frequency of what you want to measure, so if you want to measure 800Hz, you need to measure AT LEAST at 1600Hz. The higher the `Fs`, the better

Comment: Look for digital signal processing DSP forums on here... a wave requires 4 data points to plot this shape: /\/ i.e. a sawtooth of frequency 400hz. you can simply resample your data at 1600hz, your max frequency of a sound contained in FFT will be 400hz either way. you would expect 400hz changes in acceleration unless your meter was attached to a bumblebee? what kind of mad data analysis algorythm passes accelerometer data simply through an FFT? why would you include >40hz components of the signal??? of your target?

Comment: sorry you need 2 points to plot a wave signal, not 4: //////// is a series of 2 point waves i.e. -1/+1 on successive samples in series.

Answer (score 1):

Sampling frequency Fs equals the exact number of samples you get per one second. For Fs=800Hz you get a spectrum in 0:400 region.

Comment: I've resolved! It was an error on the configuration of the accelerometer